# jquery finding one object and not another next to it (works in Edge but not chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably the weirdest thing I have witnessed.

I have the following code at global scope:

```js
var status = $('#monkeyballs');
console.log(status);

var clock = $('#event-count-down');
console.log(clock);
```

```html
<div id="monkeyballs"></div>
<div id="event-count-down"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In Edge both of the `console.log`s log an actual jQuery object, while in Chrome for the "monkeyballs" div it prints out `[object Object]` and prints out the actual jQuery object for the second like it should. So the issue is not with jquery itself not working but specifically that element.

I have even tried `$(document.getElementById('monkeyballs'))` again it works in Edge and not chrome.

I have cleared my history and cache.

When I try to access any of the jQuery properties/methods I get the '' is not a function such as `Uncaught TypeError: status.removeClass is not a function
    at (index):644`

Anyone ever witness anything like this and am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added the code and markup to my post, can you not see?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you just using `$('#monkeyballs')`? If there are differences in how the browser populates the object, surely the whole point of jQuery is that it normalises these differences for you so you just use its selectors and don't have to worry about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem, it was because my variable name was `status` and Chrome seems to choke on that and after looking it up, it seems its a [predefined global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

Comment: Yet another reason not to use global variables. If this were all within a scoping function (always recommended), `status` would be just fine.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: I'd already fixed that for him, you may have seen an outdated copy of the answer.

Comment: That is the reason why best JavaScript practice is to wrap code in IIFE, to avoid such scenarios.